# .htaccess redirect to cached file if exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an index.php file in my root web dir.  I want to check if /cache/index.html exists FIRST, and if so, display it.

Otherwise, continue using /index.php

Apache is configured to display index.html first, then index.php, so one thought I had was symlink /index.html to /cache/index.html, but I would rather not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
DirectoryIndex cache/index.html index.php
```

Note that this affects all subdirectories, as well, relative to the subdirectory. If you try to load `htt://www.example.com/blub/` (and `/blub/` exists) first `/blub/cache/index.html` is searched, then `/blub/index.html`. This generally isn't a problem, but you might want to add `index.html` or other index names used at the end of the directive.